# How to add touch controls unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was creating a flappy bird game in Unity and while I was trying to add touch inputs it gave me this error

[image: Unity project]

> InvalidOperationException: You are trying to read Input using the
> UnityEngine.Input class, but you have switched active Input handling
> to Input System package in Player Settings.

**I think it's because I downloaded the new Input system from the package manager, but i removed it**

playerScript Code:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class playerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rb;
 
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) || Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(0f, 7f);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it!

You need to go to the **Player settings** *Build settings/Player settings/Other settings/Configuration* and search for:

[image]

and set ***Input manager old***

Answer (score 1):

Try change code to this

```
using UnityEngine;

public class playerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
Rigidbody2D rb;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Jump();
    }
}
public void Jump()
  {
     rb.velocity = new Vector2(0f , 7f);
  }

}
```

Then add UI button and on the `on click` drag the gameobject this script is attacked to into it, click the script and then click 'Jump()'

Comment: I did that before and with this code it has a little deelay

Answer (score 0):

You could add Giant UI button and add function jump and make it work when button is pressed. I had similar problem for visual novel game. And I added screen sized button :)

Comment: Yes I tryed it but the giant button  added a little bit of deelay